# How to modify the singleton object in kotlin native

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I am adding Kotlin native linuxX64 target support to some existing library. Library is compiled successfuly but while running the test cases, I am getting following runtime error:

```
kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException: mutation attempt of frozen kotlin.Array@1249428
    at kfun:kotlin.Exception.<init>(kotlin.String?)kotlin.Exception (0x271205)
    at kfun:kotlin.RuntimeException.<init>(kotlin.String?)kotlin.RuntimeException (0x2711c5)
    at kfun:kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException.<init>(kotlin.String)kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException (0x272595)
    at ThrowInvalidMutabilityException (0x3b0b53)
    at  (0x3b5733)
```

Even the [Object example](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html)  given in Kotlin language tutorial is not working on giving the similar runtime exception.

I know the problem is due to the frozen objects. But I could not find the proper way to modify the frozen members of singleton object.

Answer (score 3):

After searching a bit I got the answer. We can update the frozen object using the [Atomic Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.native.concurrent/-atomic-reference/index.html).